# Can a property be added to the result returned by Compare-Object cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, to compare properties of 2 objects we use `Compare-Object -Property`. Is there any way that I can add a property to the result returned?

*For example:*
This is the output of the following command:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime
```

where `$first` and `$second` are 2 objects. I want to add a property `Path` to this output.

```
Name                   Length LastWriteTime        SideIndicator
----                   ------ -------------   
ImagingEngine.dll     2360832 7/10/2015 4:31:20 PM =>           
ImagingEjsbxngine.dll 2360832 7/10/2015 4:31:20 PM <=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this maybe?

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime | 
ft *,@{n="path";e={resolve-path $_.name}}
```

edit after comment:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime -PassThru  | 
ft Name, Length, LastWriteTime , @{n="path";e={$_.fullname}}, sideindicator
```

Comment: It introduces a column called path, but is not able to get the path of the filenames returned.

Comment: @ShellyTomar if `$first` and `$second` are of type `[fileinfo]` it works. What type they are? cuold you post what `$first | fl *` returns?

Comment: $first = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Filter *.dll
$second =  Get-ChildItem -Path $path2 -Filter *.dll

So they contain all the files in a folder at some path.

Comment: I dont want comparison on the basis of fullname, as it will return all the objects from both folders as the paths will be different. I want their comparison solely on the basis of their properties (excluding the path)

Comment: @ShellyTomar I've fixed the custom property! Try now!

Comment: One more problem occurred. When I save this output in an object and export it to a file, instead of the output of this command, the property table of the object gets exported. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: @ShellyTomar try changing `ft` with `select`